# Glide - Is there a benefit of using .centerCrop() instead of android:scaleType="centerCrop" on my ImageView?

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm using the Glide image loading library to load an image into my `ImageView`.

```
Glide.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);
```

I was reading the ReadMe on how to use Glide on the github page and what I noticed is that in the sample they use the method `.centerCrop()` to crop the image.

```
Glide.with(this).load(url).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Is there any benefit of using this method over just using the `scaleType` attribute in an `ImageView`?

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

I tried it without the `.centerCrop()` method and just using the xml attribute and they essentially look the same. Does Glide have some sort of under the hood optimization that consumes less memory or something which makes that method a better choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

centerCrop doesn't do anthing to the  memory usage , it's just about scaling image

Comment: all I can say is that if you want To centerCrop programmatically in app , use glide's  centerCrop , otherwise android:scaleType="centerCrop"  doesn't make any difference